# AssertionError on ArrayList with same output

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I know that this topic has been asked by many times and I search for all possible solutions but unfortunately nothing solves my problem.

Here's my test case:

```
@Test
    public void whenFindAllBy_thenReturnListofViewPlanDetailDto() {
        java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime());
        java.sql.Date endDate = new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime());
        Plan planA = new Plan();
        planA.setName("Plan A - 2018");
        entityManager.persist(planA);
        entityManager.flush();
        Module moduleA = new Module();
        moduleA.setName("CSS");
        moduleA.setDescription("CSS is a cornerstone technology of the World Wide Web, alongside HTML and JavaScript.");
        entityManager.persist(moduleA);

        Module moduleB = new Module();
        moduleB.setName("HTML");
        moduleB.setDescription("Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications.");
        entityManager.persist(moduleB);

        PlanDetail planDetailA = new PlanDetail();
        planDetailA.setInstructor("Mozilla Firefox Foundation");
        planDetailA.setStartDate(startDate);
        planDetailA.setEndDate(endDate);
        planDetailA.setModule(moduleA);
        planDetailA.setPlan(planA);
        entityManager.persist(planDetailA);


        PlanDetail planDetailB = new PlanDetail();
        planDetailB.setInstructor("W3 Schools");
        planDetailB.setStartDate(startDate);
        planDetailB.setEndDate(endDate);
        planDetailB.setModule(moduleB);
        planDetailB.setPlan(planA);
        entityManager.persist(planDetailB);

        entityManager.flush();

        List<ViewPlanDetailDto> plandetails = new ArrayList<>();
        plandetails.add(new ViewPlanDetailDto(planDetailA.getId(), planDetailA.getModule().getName(), planDetailA.getModule().getDescription(), planDetailA.getInstructor(), planDetailA.getStartDate(), planDetailA.getEndDate()));
        plandetails.add(new ViewPlanDetailDto(planDetailB.getId(), planDetailB.getModule().getName(), planDetailB.getModule().getDescription(), planDetailB.getInstructor(), planDetailB.getStartDate(), planDetailB.getEndDate()));

        assertEquals(planRepository.findAllBy(planA.getId()), plandetails);

    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.ArrayList<[ViewPlanDetailDto(detailId=1, name=CSS, description=CSS is a cornerstone technology of the World Wide Web, alongside HTML and JavaScript., instructor=Mozilla Firefox Foundation, startDate=2018-07-06, endDate=2018-07-06), ViewPlanDetailDto(detailId=2, name=HTML, description=Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications., instructor=W3 Schools, startDate=2018-07-06, endDate=2018-07-06)]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[ViewPlanDetailDto(detailId=1, name=CSS, description=CSS is a cornerstone technology of the World Wide Web, alongside HTML and JavaScript., instructor=Mozilla Firefox Foundation, startDate=2018-07-06, endDate=2018-07-06), ViewPlanDetailDto(detailId=2, name=HTML, description=Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications., instructor=W3 Schools, startDate=2018-07-06, endDate=2018-07-06)]>
```

What I try:
Override equals on PlanDetail, ViewPlanDetailDto, Plan
but it all failed.

Equals and Hashcode overrides:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ViewPlanDetailDto))
            return false;
        ViewPlanDetailDto other = (ViewPlanDetailDto) obj;
        if (description == null) {
            if (other.description != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!description.equals(other.description))
            return false;
        if (detailId == null) {
            if (other.detailId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!detailId.equals(other.detailId))
            return false;
        if (endDate == null) {
            if (other.endDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!endDate.equals(other.endDate))
            return false;
        if (instructor == null) {
            if (other.instructor != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!instructor.equals(other.instructor))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (startDate == null) {
            if (other.startDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!startDate.equals(other.startDate))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((detailId == null) ? 0 : detailId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((endDate == null) ? 0 : endDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((instructor == null) ? 0 : instructor.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((startDate == null) ? 0 : startDate.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

When I try to assert it it always fails even though the output is identical.

Based on IntelliJ's **comparison failure**, it highlighted on the **trailing space** on the expected part which I don't get how it ended having a trailing space.

[image: Difference]

Answer (score 0):

You probably override `equals()` incorrectly .
To understand and correct your issue, you should start by the base : unit testing your `equals()` method (and by the way think of overriding `hashCode()` to be consistent with the `equals()` contract).

Whatever, overriding `equals()` by specifying all instance fields of the class to do some assertions in an unit test is generally something that you can avoid and that you have to if it gives an undesirable behavior to `equals()`.
`equals()` has a semantic defined in `Object.equals()` :

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

You should stick to that.
Generally I use a unit testing matcher library such as Harmcrest or AssertJ to perform  assertions on the object's field in a non intrusive while being simple and clear.

With AssertJ, your assertion could look like :

```
Assertions.assertThat(planRepository.findAllBy(planA.getId()))
          // assert result size
          .hasSize(2) 
          // extract a field to assert
          .extracting(ViewPlanDetailDto::getPlanDetail) 
          // extract still finer fields to assert
          .extracting(PlanDetail::getId, p -> p.getModule().getName(), p -> p.getModule().geDescription(), ... other fields to assert)
          // declare values expected
          .containsExactly(Tuple.tuple(planDetailA.getId(), "CSS", "CSS is a cornerstone technology of the World Wide Web, alongside HTML and JavaScript.",
                                       planDetailB.getId(), "HTML", "Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications.",
                                       ... other expected tuples ));
```

Comment: Do I only override the equals method in ViewPlanDetailDto?

Comment: If you choose this option, you have to override all of them. Start in a progressive way : write a unit test for each `equals()` you overrode.

Comment: Do ArrayList produce a trailing space? I've updated my question with the part which my test fails.